# Ecmascript 6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am referring to the implementation of android back button for react native but I am not sure how to interpret this snippet code(for function arguments of `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.
Isn't named parameter supposed to be using `=` sign?. 
e.g.

`var foo = function (a = 1) {}`

```
var BackAndroid = {

  exitApp: function() {
    DeviceEventManager.invokeDefaultBackPressHandler();
  },

  addEventListener: function (
    eventName: BackPressEventName,
    handler: Function
  ): {remove: () => void} {
    _backPressSubscriptions.add(handler);
    return {
      remove: () => BackAndroid.removeEventListener(eventName, handler),
    };
  },

  removeEventListener: function(
    eventName: BackPressEventName,
    handler: Function
  ): void {
    _backPressSubscriptions.delete(handler);
  },

};
```

Comment: This appears to be using the type definition system of Flow

Comment: Re. Flow see http://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html

Comment: thanks for the quick comments!

Comment: This is not true at all. Flow is for type information, tjhse are default parameters and part of ES6.

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing are default parameters. In that function it's saying if you don't pass a value for `a` or pass undefined, instead use 1.

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized
>   with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters